# Cannot read from my Resource (.res) file

Tags: delphi

I have written a simple loader to install my program and its help file.

```
unit PSInstaller;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Registry, Vcl.StdCtrls, HTMListB,
  HTMLabel, System.Zip;

type
  TfmPDSInstaller = class(TForm)
    HTMLabel1: THTMLabel;
    HTMListBox1: THTMListBox;
    btnNext: TButton;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    function InstallFile(ResID: integer; pName: String): Boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  fmPDSInstaller: TfmPDSInstaller;

implementation

{$R 'ProtonStudio32.res' 'ProtonStudio32.rc'}
{$R *.dfm}

Var IDEDirectory: String;

Const APP = 100;
      HELP = 200;

procedure TfmPDSInstaller.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HTMListBox1.AddItem('Copying Proton Studio to Proton IDE directory',nil);
  if InstallFile(APP, 'Studio Application') then begin
    HTMListBox1.AddItem('Copying Proton Studio Help to Proton IDE directory',nil);
    If InstallFile(HELP, 'Studio Help') then
      HTMListBox1.AddItem('Proton Studio Installed', nil);
  end;
end;

function TfmPDSInstaller.InstallFile(ResID: integer; pName: String): Boolean;
Var rs: TResourceStream;
    Zip: TZipFile;
    s: String;
begin
  Result := false;
  try
    Rs := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(HInstance, ResID, RT_RCDATA);
    Zip := TZipFile.Create;
    try
      Zip.Open(Rs,zmRead);
      Zip.ExtractAll(IDEDirectory);
    finally
      Rs.Free;
      Zip.Free;
      Result := true;
    end;
  except
    on EFOpenError do
      s  := 'Unable to Open resource ' + pName;
    else
      s := 'Unable to Copy file from resource ' + pName;
  end;
  HTMListBox1.AddItem(s, nil);
end;

procedure TfmPDSInstaller.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Close;
end;

procedure TfmPDSInstaller.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  btnNext.Enabled := false;
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  HTMListBox1.AddItem('Checking for ProtonIDE',nil);
  if Reg.OpenKey('Software\MecaniqueUK\ProtonIDE\Install', false) then begin
    IDEDirectory := Reg.ReadString('IDE');
    Reg.CloseKey;
  end;
  Reg.Free;
end;

procedure TfmPDSInstaller.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnNext.Enabled := false;
  if DirectoryExists(IDEDirectory) then begin
    HTMListbox1.AddItem('Click Next to install Proton Studio in ' + IDEDirectory, nil);
    btnNext.Enabled := true;
  end
  else
    HTMListBox1.AddItem('Proton IDE must be installed first', nil);
end;    
end.
```

I  have created a .rc script to load my program and help

```
#100 RT_RCDATA "D:\Data\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\ProtonNewIDE\Win32\Debug\ProtonNewIDE.zip"
#200 RT_RCDATA "D:\Data\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\ProtonNewIDE\Win32\Debug\Proton Studio.zip"
```

I'm working in Delphi Berlin 10.1, Build resulted in my resource file being generated and I can open it in my Resource Editor but when I try and open the resource:

```
Rs := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(Application.Handle, ResID, RT_RCDATA);
```

I get an Address violation.  It breaks in System.Classes at this point:

```
  HResInfo := FindResource(Instance, Name, ResType);
```

and both the Name and  ResType are empty.

I would appreciate a pointer to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think the `Application.Handle` is the correct parameter for `TResourceStream.CreateFromID`. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TResourceStream.CreateFromID): _The Instance parameter is the instance handle associated with the executable or shared library that contains the resource._ I think `HInstance` from `SysInit` should be correct.

Comment: Well that got me a little further along, I now get a Resource not found 100 error.

Comment: I noticed that RT_DATA is not being properly recognised.  When I hover  the mouse over  it I get RT_RCDATA - erroneous type and when I debug in Classes.TResourceStream.CreateFromID ResType is ''

Comment: Sorted it now - RT_RCDATA had to be a string Rs := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(HInstance, ResID, 'RT_RCDATA')

Comment: RT_RCDATA should be fine. For sure it's not a valid string. It's a sentinel value. Yes you can use a string version but that is not idiomatic.

Comment: `RT_RCDATA` is defined in the `(Winapi.)Windows` and `(System.)Types` units (depending on your version of Delphi).

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a window handle instead of a module handle. Pass `HInstance` instead, the handle to the module containing this code.